Fix missing POM warning for an undeclared version
While running the maven project, my maven enforcer plugin gives a warning like the below, but I haven't declared that particular version. How to solve this ?
[WARNING] The POM for com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11 is missing, no dependency information available

Tried maven dependency tree no transitive dependency for that version as well

have you tried checking your dependency tree? maybe you don't call it, but one of your dependencies does

What have you actually declared? [edit] your question and add [mre] details. The pom should be part of the question. Also add the effective pom (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html).

The simple issue is that a version 1.11 does not exist... but it does exist a version 1.11.0 ... apart from ancient old... 2016... I recommend to use a more recent version of those dependencies...
